# Hierarchical clustering in R

Tags: r, regression, clustering, hierarchical-clustering

I have a dataset of around 25 observations and most of them being categorical. 
I have three questions for this.
    1- Do the covariates I pick for hierarchical clustering matter or should I try and include as many covariates as I can?
    2- Is it possible to do hierarchical clustering for the whole data set, including the categorical data?
    3- I want to reduce the levels on two covariates. My thought was to do hierarchical clustering for both of them using the same variables. I won't be using the results from one cluster in another. Would I run into any problems by doing this?

Comment: How many variables have you got and how many categories on each? One point is shown by the trivial case of 2 categorical variables each with 2 categories, in which case observations classify themselves into at most 4 groups. Conversely if even some variables have several categories, then the number of jointly defined categories possible far exceeds the number of observations. I have seen posts where there were say 4 binary variables, so no fancy method was needed beyond a table of which of the 16 possibilities occurred and how often.

Answer (score 1):

HAC can run on any distance matrix (although some variants such as Ward *assume* it is Euclidean or squared Euclidean, so check the documentation!).

In particular, you can try a **Gower distance** matrix.

The main problems with categorical attributes are: *weighting* because the features usually are not all equally important and *interpretation* of the results. Sure, you got clusters. But are they better than "random"? You can get almost any result just by playing around with the parameters.